# Protobuf DynamicMessage parse

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, proto, protobuf-java

I am trying to parse generic  protobuf messages using java. It works fine with `Oneof` or simple types, but with `Any` i have a problem.

```
private static DynamicMessage parseData(byte[] data) throws IOException, Descriptors.DescriptorValidationException {
    DescriptorProtos.FileDescriptorSet set = DescriptorProtos.FileDescriptorSet.parseFrom(new FileInputStream("file1.desc");
    DescriptorProtos.FileDescriptorSet any = DescriptorProtos.FileDescriptorSet.parseFrom(new FileInputStream("any.desc"));
    var anyDesc = Descriptors.FileDescriptor.buildFrom(any.getFile(0), new Descriptors.FileDescriptor[] {});
    Descriptors.FileDescriptor
        md = Descriptors.FileDescriptor.buildFrom(set.getFile(0), new Descriptors.FileDescriptor[] {anyDesc});
    Descriptors.Descriptor messageType = md.getMessageTypes().get(0);
    return DynamicMessage.parseFrom(messageType, data);
}
```

My schema

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/protobuf/any.proto";

message SearchRequest {
  string query = 1;
  int32 page_number = 2;
  int32 result_per_page = 3;
  google.protobuf.Any test = 4;
}

message Test2 {
  string one = 1;
  string two = 2;
  string three = 3;
}

message Test3 {
  string one = 1;
}
```

This test code works, and i got message

```
query: "sad"
page_number: 1
result_per_page: 123
test {
  type_url: "type.googleapis.com/Test2"
  value: "\n\003one\022\003two\032\005three"
}
```

And here is the problem. `Any` field is not parsed.
How could i achieve this?

I need to parse Any field by `type_url` name. But i do not have place where where it can be done.

P.S. Iterate over generated dynamicMessage and check if field is Any and then parse it seems not a good idea, as i will have nested any.

My main goal is to parse messages by protobuf schema and convert to json. Schemas will change, so i can`t use approach with generated class.

This is test code.

Comment: You must (recursively) descend through the message. [`any`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#any) messages are protobufs embedded within another message. So, when encountered, generally you'd lookup the `type_url` to find the descriptor or, if dynamically decoding, you'd then need to begin parsing again as you've found an entirely new protobuf message.... Since `any` can be nested, you need to repeat until you've decoded all the turtles.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with recursive method. I go via all fields and check if any is Any field and parse it by type_url